# plot a bar chart of data grouped by categories in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

In matlab, is it possible to plot a bar chart of data grouped by categories?

For example, say I have imported an excel file containing the following columns of data:

```
Year    Month    Species    Count
2005      2       spider      5
2005      4      mosquito     8
2006      1       midge       4
2008      4       spider      3
```

The figure should have time along the x-axis (months and years) and Count on the y-axis. A grouped bar chart (different colours for different species) should be plotted at the corresponding time points (note that there are missing time points when Count=0).

Comment: It is possible (http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) but we'll need more information to give any specific advice.

Comment: Thanks @David - what other info? There are ~5 different species and the time range is between 2004 and 2012. Thanks.

Comment: A small sample of how your data is saved would help, whether it is a matrix, a cell array etc.

Comment: OK @David, sorry! After importing the (very large) excel file into Matlab, I now have four column vectors called "Year", "Month, "Species" and "Count".

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, with some randomly generated data. You will have to check the matrix `D` and see if it structured the same as your data.

```
clear,clc,close
Y=[2013:1:2014];
for i=1:length(Y)
    for j=1:12
        for k=1:3
            D(i,j,k)=randi(5)-1;
        end
    end
end

for i=1:3
    t=squeeze(D(:,:,i)).';
    M(:,i)=t(:).';
end
bar(M)
```

---

I am assuming that you can create `D` to be the same as I did. You will need to convert the strings in `Species` to numbers using, e.g.:

```
Species={'spider';'midge';'mosquito';'spider'}
S=zeros(size(Species))
S(strcmp(Species,'spider'))=1
S(strcmp(Species,'midge'))=2
S(strcmp(Species,'mosquito'))=3
```

then `D=[Year Month S Count]`.

---

Hopefully the idea helps you at least.